# Insert a character that isn't present on my keyboard on Linux Mint

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

How can I use `Alt+<ASCII CODE>` on Linux (Mint 16) on a netbook which doesn't have a num pad nor a "Num lock" button?

I found lots of tutorials for Windows, but no one with Linux.
I also tried using Alt+"Fn" key but I just get some strange behavior on terminal,like (while running `gdb`) :

```
(arg: 23)
```

Comment: I would use the virtual keyboard or program some macro

Comment: is there any virtual keyboard on Linux Mint?

Comment: http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/12/how-to-enable-screen-keyboard-virtual.html ?

Comment: I tried it, but someway the applet (widget) uses only a third of the screen and is horizontally squeezed (and not resizable) so that is completely useless

Comment: You can also try onboard I don't know if it's the same http://www.linuxandlife.com/2013/06/virtual-keyboard-linux-mint-mate.html

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you mean by ASCII code? What do you want to see printed?

Comment: for example: { } I tried onboard for Ubuntu (hence, compatible with Mint) by it doesn't run (errors), I also tried another virtual keyboard, it works.. expect for alt combinations..

Comment: @terdon pretty sure (s)he's refering to that antique IBM PC feature that Windows still promotes, see my answer.

Comment: @Gilles ah, yes, pretty sure you're right.

Comment: [Linux alternative to alt+numpad codes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/254477/44425)

Answer (score 5):

If you mean the feature where you hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and press digits on the numeric keypad, and when you release <kbd>Alt</kbd> the character with the corresponding number¹ is inserted, this isn't working for you because it's a feature of the IBM PC that Windows copied and that the Linux console copied but which the Linux GUI doesn't offer.

Under unix systems, the usual method for entering a character that isn't on your keyboard is a [Compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key). Rather than memorize numbers, you press <kbd>Compose</kbd> and then 2 (sometimes more) characters on your keyboard. For example, <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> enters `é`, <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd><</kbd> <kbd><</kbd> enters `«`, etc.

I don't know if Linux Mint has a Compose key enabled by default. Unfortunately, PC keyboards lack a key labeled “Compose”, so there is no standard as to which key to choose; the “Windows/Menu” key (which isn't always convenient on a laptop) or the Caps Lock key are common choices. Pull up the keyboard layout settings and make sure you have a Compose key set up.

If you need to enter a Unicode character by its number, in many applications, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and then enter a hexadecimal number.

When it comes to rarely-used characters, where you wouldn't memorize the number anyway, there are more convenient ways to insert those characters than looking up the number and typing it. You can use a character map application such as [Gucharmap](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gucharmap) to locate a character and copy it to the clipboard. You can look up the character on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/) and copy it. You can draw the character on [Shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/) and copy it.

[This page describes these possibilities on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey). I think Linux Mint is fairly similar.

¹  <sub>[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) only goes up to 127 so this is rarely used for ASCII codes.</sub>

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+U worked like a charm for me :3