# Linux alternative to alt+numpad codes

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, unicode

I sometimes need to type "alt codes" to get symbols and on linux, it can be inefficient to use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> then type the code, for example <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>+<kbd>00a7</kbd> for § when on Windows it's <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>21</kbd>.

So what I'm asking is, is there any way to basically use <kbd>alt</kbd>+... for these symbols as I don't really like using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> and it doesn't work in some places.

I use `xfce4` as my desktop environment and under the keyboard settings, I've seen something called a "compose key." As I didn't know what this was, I looked it up and saw it kind of had something to do with these unicode characters.

I've also seen somethings along the lines of level 1, 2, 3 and 4 keys but I don't really understand how these work, so if someone could explain these as well, that would be great.

(I use arch (manjaro more specifically) if this helps)

Comment: I am curious about the meaning/origin of your username "bytesnottights". I mean, I guess I sometimes handle bytes, and yet I happen to be wearing tights right now... :-)

Comment: you can use text expansion, for example it set it up so when i type ;up it automatically insert the ↑ alt code. i use a program called autokey for that and there's another cool one called espanso

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> (as well as a few other synonymous sequences) to obtain the character §. This is both shorter and more mnemonic than <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd> (you didn't mention pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> but I had to do that do get it to work for me). The compose sequences are meant to be easy to remember, such as <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> for ± or <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> for é. IMHO that's certainly better than having to remember Unicode code point numbers!

You can find the list of compose sequences in the various `Compose` files in `/usr/share/X11/locale`. Check out `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` in particular which appears to contain one of the biggest collections. Note that you will see <kbd>Multi_key</kbd> in that file, which is the "official" X11 name of the key more commonly known as <kbd>Compose</kbd>.

Sorry, I don't know anything about <kbd>alt</kbd>+... which you mention. Personally, compose sequences meet all my needs for typing English, French, and occasional special symbols (but not Japanese, of course).

> I've also seen somethings along the lines of level 1, 2, 3 and 4

I don't know what that means, but maybe it refers to the length of the compose key sequence? Not all of the sequences are two characters. Some are 3 characters long: <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> results in — (mnemonic: 3 hyphens because an em-dash is very wide) and I guess some are even longer (though I don't know any of those offhand).

Comment: This post just saved me a lot of time. :)

Comment: What exactly is the "compose" or "multi_key" key? (Windows keyboard here)

Comment: (a little dismayed to learn that such a thing as a "Windows keyboard" exists — so, like, apparently now keyboards are operating-system-specific?) Few keyboards these days have physical keys labelled Compose, but since a compose key is much more useful than a second Alt key or a second Meta key, many people map one of those less-than-useful redundant keys in the bottom right corner to Compose. You can easily find instructions on the Internet on how to do that, both using the command line (`setxkbmap` for temporary changes that aren't saved, etc...) and GUI settings.

Comment: “I don't know what that means, but maybe it refers to the length of the compose key sequence?”—No.  “Levels” are things like the “base level” (no shift) and “shift level” (shift level activated/caps lock active).  The US standard layout has only these two levels.  Many European keyboards have three levels or more.  Xkb allows for up to eight levels.

Comment: Celada, what is the compose key? I've never seen this on any of my UK English or US English keyboards. Are you using an old keyboard from a VT200 terminal or some old DEC or Sun Systems keyboard?

Comment: The compose key is here: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/de/Compose_key_on_LK201_keyboard.jpg/220px-Compose_key_on_LK201_keyboard.jpg And sincerely, I never saw it in my whole life on any European keyboard.

Comment: **"(you didn't mention pressing `Enter` but I had to do that do get it to work for me)"** saved me. I just did not expect that in Unicode Code Point, for example an underlined written u3251 resulting from `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`u`+ 3251 on the numpad really turns into a circled 21 after pressing enter (draw.io, LibreOffice Writer, ...), at first I thought, it would not work, since I did not know that an `Enter` is needed.

Comment: The compose key is whatever key you set it to; typically it's the `Windows` key, but you can set it to be another one if you want. Consider the *Compose* key to the be the **Super** key.