# How do I type German or Spanish characters in Linux when I don't use a desktop environment?

Tags: keyboard, locale

I'm using Debian 9 x64 with the [dwm](https://dwm.suckless.org/) window manager. I don't use Gnome, KDE, [Xfce](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/254477/49592), or any other desktop environment; it's just the window manager.

I [configured my keyboard layout](https://superuser.com/a/404507) to use the Generic 105-key international keyboard. I've tried <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (the right Alt key) plus [various alt codes](https://www.alt-codes.net/german_alt_codes/), to no avail. I've also tried <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and then <kbd>"</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd> or <kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd>, with similarly disappointing results.

Ideally I would be able to type these characters anywhere, including text editors (all of mine support Unicode), web browsers, etc. I don't use LibreOffice, so some of the LibreOffice-specific solutions I find aren't enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a step. You need to set a [Compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) first. For example, to set the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key as the Compose key:

```
setxkbmap -layout us -option compose:ralt
```

Then:

1. Press <kbd>Compose</kbd> (on my keyboard it's labelled <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>) **and release it**.
2. Press the sequence of keys that correspond to the letter/diacritic you want. These are sometimes intuitive, sometimes not. Sometimes the order doesn't matter, either, e.g. in the case of accents.

   - To insert ß, press <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd>
   - For umlauts, e.g. ü, press <kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd>
   - For accents, e.g. á, press <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> or <kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>
   - For ñ, press <kbd>n</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>~</kbd>

You can see the [full list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key#Common_compose_combinations) or in the image below:

[image: compose key: common combinations]

Answer (score -1):

If it is for a few char, you can use :

```
Ctrl+Shift+U Enter 'utf8 code of your char' Enter
```

You can find the utf8 code [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/)

Comment: This works in programs that support it, e.g. Firefox, but it doesn't work everywhere (in some terminals, for example, or the SciTe text editor without additional modification).